# php setcookie fails under php5

Tags: php, setcookie

I created this simple script which will either set a cookie with three values or retrieve the cookies values if they are already set.  On my server running PHP4, everything works.   On my server with PHP 5 (5.2.11), the script fails to set the cookie in the browser.  I already checked if output buffering is enabled in my php.ini and it is.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this fails to work?

```
<?php 
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
echo "<body>";
if (!isset($_COOKIE['taeinv'])) {
    echo "No cookie set...   Attempting to set a new cookie.";
    $user = "testuser";
    $role = "admin";
    $expire = "true";
    $halfHour = 1800;
    setcookie("websitename[Expire]", $expire, time()+$halfHour);
    setcookie("websitename[User]", $user, time()+$halfHour);
    setcookie("websitename[Role]", $role, time()+$halfHour);
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['websitename'])) {
    echo "Cookie Values:";
    echo "<br />";
        foreach ($_COOKIE['websitename'] as $name => $value) {
            echo "<b>$name</b> : $value <br />\n";
        }
}
echo "<br />";
echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the cookie before any output to the browser. Try moving all `echo` lines somewhere below the `setcookie` call. You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$set = false;
if (!isset($_COOKIE['taeinv'])) {
    $set = true;
    $user = "testuser";
    $role = "admin";
    $expire = "true";
    $halfHour = 1800;
    setcookie("websitename[Expire]", $expire, time()+$halfHour);
    setcookie("websitename[User]", $user, time()+$halfHour);
    setcookie("websitename[Role]", $role, time()+$halfHour);

}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
echo "<body>";
if ($set) {
    echo "No cookie set...   Attempted to set a new cookie.";
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['websitename'])) {
    echo "Cookie Values:";
    echo "<br />";
        foreach ($_COOKIE['websitename'] as $name => $value) {
            echo "<b>$name</b> : $value <br />\n";
        }
}
echo "<br />";
echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked on my old PHP4 server, but not on PHP5.

Comment: Don't add comments as new answers. Instead write comments to answers. What is the error message? Do you have any spaces before the opening `<?php` tag? You also might have an invisible UTF-8 BOM if there are no spaces or other symbols.

Comment: No spaces before the <?php tag

Comment: I just removed the original file and copy and pasted the code to a new  file in nano in the terminal.  It still fails to set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Use **output buffering** – [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_end_flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php).

**Example:**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    echo '<p>Initializing…</p>';
    setcookie('myLanguage', 'PHP');
    ob_end_flush();
    // you can continue your PHP code here…
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but it was only in Chrome that the cookies disappeared. Firefox was fine.

Setting all the parameters in the `setcookie` function fixed it.

This sets the cookie but Chrome drops the cookie within a click:

```
setcookie('uname', 'Joe', time()+3600*24);
```

This sets the cookie and the browser retains it:

```
setcookie('uname', 'Joe', time()+3600*24, '/', 'www.domain.com', false, false);
```